Android java MSAL Error: Failed to acquire token with Interactive Browser Authentication
In my Anroid Java app, I would like to offer users the option of searching for and downloading their files from Onedrive.
I use the Android Java example from official documentation.
The example works, I receive the access token.
It's not clear to me what happens next.
I can't find in the documentation how to pass the access token to the GraphServiceClient or the AuthProvider.
Creating the GraphServiceClient Object:
final InteractiveBrowserCredential interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialBuilder()
     .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
     .redirectUrl(REDIRECT_URL)
     .build();

final TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(SCOPES, interactiveBrowserCredential);
final GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();

buidling DriveItem:
DriveItem rootItem = graphClient
    .me()
    .drive()
    .root()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();

causes to this Exception:
ExecutionException: com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: Failed to acquire token with Interactive Browser Authentication.
implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:5.1.0'
implementation 'com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph:5.77.0'
implementation 'com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph-core:2.0.21'
implementation 'com.azure:azure-identity:1.11.0'

I'm in a bit of a pickle now.
Can someone please help me, thank you
GGK

Create a Microsoft Entra ID application and enable public flow like below:

Grant API permissions like below:

To authenticate GraphServiceClient and access OneDrive, modify the code like below:
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
final String clientId = "ClientID";
final String tenantId = "TenantID"; 
final String[] scopes = new String[] {"Files.Read.All"};
final InteractiveBrowserCredential credential = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialBuilder()
.clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).build();
if (null == scopes || null == credential) {
throw new Exception("Unexpected error");
}

final GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes);
Drive result = graphClient.me().drive().get();
System.out.println(result.getId());
}
}

I got the Drive ID successfully:

To get the drive root, modify the code with below request:
DriveItem result = graphClient.drives().byDriveId("{drive-id}").root().get();

Reference:
Get a driveItem resource - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft 

Thanks, I'm not sure where in azure localhost is set as the redirect url (I'm using different language settings in the Azure portal). You can provide more detailed information, please

Go to Authentication -> Add platform as Mobile and desktop application -> set redirect URl as http://localhost

Ok, Thanks...same error...actully I use "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me" as endpoint (like set in the example App).

You can't use me directly make use of the query I mentioned in the answer or the in the doc

Check this MsDoc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#request the code doesn't pass me where as the http request contains me

I know this doc, there is requestAdapter needed, but don't find any documentation what this is. I've never seen such a weird documentation.

RequestAdapter is nothing but this line final GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes);

I used "     final GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes);
Log.d(TAG, "graphClient: "+graphClient.getRequestAdapter());
DriveItem result = graphClient.drives().byDriveId("{drive-id}").root().get();"...same crash...

Did you try to execute the code provided in my answer

yes, I tried all....always the same result

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I used tthe code in the example app, with volley to get the token.. then I'm use code posted in ma question

no, Your solution doesn' t work for me

Did you get it work by other way?

i have already invested a lot of time and am putting the topic aside for the first time

This answer is not working for Android. it only works for general Java. in Android, no browser intent is triggered by this code, resulting in a null GraphServiceClient
